# ruby watir-webdriver using a variable in a hash

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I am trying to create hash that has a vairable in the middle of it.  I can't seem to get the variable to be seen as a variable only as a literal.  Variable is an element in an array colors
Such as

```
text1 = {:style => 'background-color: variable;'}
```

I thought this would work.

```
text1 = {:style => 'background-color: #{variable};'}
```

The following works but it is a round-about-approach

```
text2 = ''
text2  << "background-color: " << variable << ";"
text1 = {:style => text2}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to insert variables into a string using `#{}`, then you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
variable = "green"
text1 = {:style => "background-color: #{variable};"}  #Notice the double quotes
#=> {:style=>"background-color: green;"}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought quotes and double quotes were synonymous/interchangeable in ruby?

Comment: They have some small differences - see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings